# Alexa skill - how to read a resultset row by row

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I get a list of rows from an API call inside my lambda. I want my alexa skill intent to read a row at a time and read the next only after confirmation.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!
Anshuman

Comment: you could give a little more details on what you have achieved or tried, but in general session attributes for alexa could help, something similar to this https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/2279543b-ed7b-48b4-a3aa-d273f7aab609/alexa-skill-recipe-using-session-attributes-to-enable-repeat-responses

Comment: Hello Anshuman. Please add more details to your question. I published a skill with this functionality, however, I do not know if it will be of use to you. Can you add details such as what language are you using, SDK version, the response you get when doing the get request, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `sessionAttributes` to read row by row. When your backend receives the initial request, query the external service and respond back with the first row and keep the array of rows in  `sessionAttributes`. You can also set a `STATE` attribute too, so that you can check this `state` in `AMAZON.YesIntent` or other confirmation handlers before you give the next row. This `STATE` attribute will help you to validate whether the confirmation is actually for reading next row.

Ex:

```
"sessionAttributes": {
    "row": ["This is the first row","This is the second row", ..  ],
    "index": 1,
    "STATE": "READING_ROWS"
  }
```

Since you want the users to confirm before reading the second row, you should append some confirmation message also with the response.

> Ex: "This is the first row. Do you want to hear more?"

**Use AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent**

When the user say **"next"** check whether the `state` is `READING_ROWS` and based on the `index` give the next item from your list. And in `sessionAttributes` increment the `index`.

Similarly, for `AMAZON.NoIntent` provide a proper response when the users denies.

More on sessionAttributes and Response Parameters [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-parameters)